# Translation from R to Python: index of last nonzero element in a row

Tags: python, r

Suppose I have an R dataframe that contains 10 rows and 60 columns. From a certain point forward, for each row, there are many trailing zeros in the columns. The last column contains a class identity. For example:

```
1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, .., 0
1, 5, 9, 10, 2, 0, 0, ..., 1
```

The first row belongs to class 0 and the second row belongs to class 1. They each have many zeros. I would like to isolate the nonzero components.

I have the R function below, which works in R:

```
keep_max = list()
for(i in 1:nrow(train_data)) {
       keep_max[[i]] = max(which(train_data[i,1:(ncol(train_data)-1)] > 0))
}
```

[EDIT: For example, with the two rows given above, this would return a list containing elements 3 and 5, which are the indices of the last nonzero elements in each row (except for the last value, which I don't want to include because it's a class label)].

I am looking for a Python 2.7 equivalent. I have tried:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
        x1 = np.where(x_orig[i]==max(x_orig[i,:]))
```

But this gives me the maximum of the row, not the index of the last nonzero element in the row.

I have also tried:

```
np.where(x_orig[i]==max(x_orig[i,(0:x_orig.shape[1]-1)] >0))
```

but I got a syntax error.

How can I find the index of the last nonzero element in the row (except for the last entry, as that can be a class identity of 0), using Python 2.7?

Thank you!

Comment: As an aside, your R code could be shortened to `max.col(train_data[-ncol(train_data)] != 0, "last")` which should be orders of magnitude faster than looping over rows.

Answer (score 1):

The `np.nonzero` command will give you the indices of all non-zero elements. So if you just want to exclude the last column, I'd do:

```
import numpy as np
x_orig = np.array([(1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
               (1, 5, 9, 10, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)])
row, col = np.nonzero(x_orig[:,:-1]) # these are the indices
row, col
>> (array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Now if you *only* want the last non-zero item you can do something like:

```
keep_max = []
for i in range(x_orig.shape[0]):
    keep_max.append([i, col[row == i][-1]])
>> keep_max # again these are the indices of the last non-zero element for each row
[[0, 2], [1, 4]] # i.e. 1st row-3rd element, 2nd row-5th element
```

Comment: Thank you, but the solution does not work. All I get are the list of indices of the rows and columns (all rows and columns, not just the ones that satisfy the condition). Any idea why?

Comment: @StatsSorceress, I don't know why that could be. It works for me. Also, I'm updating the code above with the example you provided, to make things cleared, and adding a way of just getting the last non-zero element.

Answer (score 0):

Example data:

```
train_data = [1,5,9,10,2,0,0,0,0,0,1]
```

If you're looking for a one-liner:

```
max([i for i, x in enumerate(train_data[:-1]) if x != 0])
```

If you're looking for efficiency, you can start from the front or end (depending on if you're expecting more or less zeros than other values) and see when the zeros start/end.

```
for i, x in enumerate(train_data):
    if x == 0:
        i = i - 1
        break
```

Note that `i` must be decremented when the first `0` is encountered to get the index of the last nonzero element.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm looking for something that will work with the equivalent of a data frame. That is, I have an array in Python with 10 rows and 60 columns. The one-liner you posted gives me this error: "
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Comment: You need to make sure that whatever is being `enumerate`d is a one-dimensional list. So if your `train_data` was a 2-dimensional list, you'd want to apply it to every "row" `train_data[i]` rather than just `train_data`.